# Why groupby with an aggregate function doesn't return grouped colums if I set as_index = False?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'books':['bk1','bk1','bk1','bk2','bk2','bk3'], 'price': [12,12,12,15,15,17]})
print(df)

        books  price
    0   bk1     12
    1   bk1     12
    2   bk1     12
    3   bk2     15
    4   bk2     15
    5   bk3     17
    
df.groupby(['books'], as_index=True).agg(asd = ('price', sum))

         asd
books       
bk1       36
bk2       30
bk3       17
```

But I want the result looks like SQL style

```
    books  asd
0   bk1     36
1   bk2     30
2   bk3     17
```

so, if I set `as_index = False`, then grouped colums doesn't return and *asd* column is not referring to the *price*.

```py
df.groupby(['books'], as_index=False).agg(asd = ('price', sum))

   asd
0  bk1
1  bk2
2  bk3
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: *so, if I set as_index = False, then grouped colums doesn't return and asd column is not referring to the price.* - It works fine for me. I see books and asd columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `reset_index`

```
df = df.groupby(['books'], as_index=True).agg(asd = ('price', sum)).reset_index()
  books  asd
0   bk1   36
1   bk2   30
2   bk3   17
```